# How to set slug in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a slug of user todo's in MongoDB but I am not able to do that.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const slug = require('slugs');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please Enter your Name',
    },
    bio: String,
    todos: [
        {
            task: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                required: 'Please Enter your Task',
            },
            slug: String,
            dueDate: Date,
            dueTime: String,
        },
    ],
});

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this.isModified(this.todos.$.task)) return next();
    this.todos.$.slug = slug(this.todos.$.task);
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

As far as I know this is how you create slug in mongoDB. But when I am creating the `todos` it is not saving the `slug` in the database, everything else is working.